# Problem with dredge function in MuMIn "result is empty" and "missing values in object" despite dataset seeming to be complete

Tags: r, mumin, glmm

I get the following error message when I run the dredge function :

```
Fixed term is "(Intercept)"
Error in dredge(global.model = ChangeModel, evaluate = TRUE, rank = "AICc") : 
  result is empty
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
```

The warnings all read as follows:

```
Warning messages:
1: In na.fail.default(structure(list(Change_YN = c(0,  ... :
  missing values in object (model 0 skipped)
```

The code I am using is

```
dredge(global.model = ChangeModel, evaluate = TRUE, rank = "AICc")
```

With the ChangeModel having been made with the glmer function.

Obviously I have gone wrong somewhere but I am not sure where. The original model doesn't include any NA, which seems to be the reason why others have had this problem, such as in this previous post : [How to fix error in MuMIn package, dredge() function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56246123/how-to-fix-error-in-mumin-package-dredge-function). Any ideas as to the cause of the problem here?